# Splitting a string into words has resulted in splitting into letters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Javascript. I need to split a string of this format:

```
["Man1","SKC2","fsdfds3","ETA4","Star5","SCity 6","TESTGB11"]
```

and create as options for select tag. I tried the below code

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {                  
    $('#bu_group').append($('<option/>', { 
        value: value,
        text : value 
    }));
});
```

But I get strings split as letters.
What can I do to split the string to get options as

```
<option>Man1</option>
<option>SKC2</option>
```

Note : Some times this string may contain spaces as well.

Comment: What is `data`? You'll need something like `$.each(data.split("-"), ...)`, where `-` is your delimiter.

Comment: @Matt var data=["Man1","SKC2","fsdfds3","ETA4","Star5","SCity 6","TESTGB11"]

Comment: What are you trying to split ? What is your source data ? Split by what ?

Comment: @user3004356 What you're showing in your comment is just an array ? What do you need to do with it ?

Comment: @user3004356 If that's actually your JavaScript to define the variable, that's not a string, it's an array.

Comment: @user3004356 `data` is already an array, you don't need to split it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Then in my firebug typeof says string

Comment: How do you get the `data`? If it is comming from the server as a response for ajax request just set `dataType` to be `json`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I get it from PHP script. I'm using jquery ajax

Comment: @user3004356 Then just set `$.ajax({dataType: 'json', ...})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `data` is your string, then parse it from JSON to a JavaScript array of strings, then iterate over that:

```
var yourArray = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(yourArray, function(index, value) {
    $('#bu_group').append($('<option/>', { 
        value: value,
        text : value 
    }));
});
```

Comment: damn, you beat my by a minute :D

Comment: Correct. Can you tell me why it was splitting into letters before

Comment: Because looping over a string gives 1 iteration per character.

Comment: @user3004356 '["A", "B", "C"]' is not the same as : ["A", "B", "C"].

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the array first and then pass the translated array as the html string,

```
$('#bu_group').html($.map(JSON.parse(data),function(val,i){
  return "<option value="+ val +">" + val + "</option>";
}));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/jZr4w/1/)

Answer (score 1):

As `data` is actually coming from your server via ajax you can simply specify correct dataType.

Either

```
$.ajax({dataType: 'json', ...}).done(function(data){
   //data will be parsed
});
```

Or

```
$.getJSON(url).done(function(data){
   //data will be parsed
});
```

Or configure your server to return correct mime type (application/json)

Answer (score 0):

if your data is

```
["Man1","SKC2","fsdfds3","ETA4","Star5","SCity 6","TESTGB11"]
```

then there is no problem, so I think you have your data as :

```
'["Man1","SKC2","fsdfds3","ETA4","Star5","SCity 6","TESTGB11"]'
```

which you must 'parse' it.

as you are using jQuery, one option is to `parseJSON` like this:

```
var parsed_array = $.parseJSON('["Man1","SKC2","fsdfds3","ETA4","Star5","SCity 6","TESTGB11"]');
```

after doing that, you can successfully do :

```
$.each(parsed_array, function (index, value) {                  
                        $('#bu_group').append($('<option/>', { 
                            value: value,
                            text : value 
                        }));
});
```

Comment: Why not `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: older browsers (IE7 for instance) mostly don't have it.

Comment: Humm. < IE8 has got < 0.5% of the browser share these days. Maybe it's time to stop supporting them ;) (it's not my -1 btw).

Comment: @Matt I don't see a problem when you already have jQuery that actually checks if browser support and use JSON.parse either way. But I guess there's no need unless really needed.

Comment: When I originally commented on your answer, you had `eval()` as the first suggestion and jQuery next. I'd **never** recommend `eval()` these days (let alone first), because of the widespread support of `JSON.parse()` and `$.parseJSON()`. My comment was more directed at that, than the recommendation of `$.parseJSON()`.

Comment: @Matt I removed the eval because can be misinterpreted. I said easy and **evil** way. I pointed out to help him understand the issue, but later I realized this can be non-intuitive so I removed it. I didn't recommended eval at all. (pretty sure that got the -1, I wasn't clear enough so it's well deserved)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data as

```
var data=["Man1","SKC2","fsdfds3","ETA4","Star5","SCity 6","TESTGB11"]
```

then you can iterate this var, isn't it?

```
var data=["Man1","SKC2","fsdfds3","ETA4","Star5","SCity 6","TESTGB11"];

for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {                  
    $('#bu_group').append($('<option/>', { 
        value: data[i],
        text : data[i] 
    }));
};
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jZr4w/)